# Calculating Maximum Index of Coincidence

Tags: index-of-coincidence

I'm trying to understand how the maximum Index of Coincidence (IC) is found. This is the only description I have for it:

"For a given period $P$ you can divide a cipher into $P$ groups, calculate the IC for each group, then take the average of these $P$ values. Doing this for all periods from 1 to 15 and selecting the maximum of these 15 values gives a MIC statistic"

Just to make sure I understand it correctly if I have a text with a length of 100 characters I should calculate the IC for:
... 100 characters 
... two sets of 50 characters 
... three sets of 33 characters (or 34?)
... four sets of 25 characters

and so on until I have my 15 groups of $P$

Then I take the maximum IC from each of the groups of $P$ and

```
sum = sum + count * (count - 1);
```

Then

```
sum / totcount * totcount - 1
```

Sorry if I don't understand I'm new to cryptoanalysis

Comment: could you provide the definition where you found? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_coincidence) is good for starters.

Comment: yes here it is; https://bionsgadgets.appspot.com/gadget_forms/acarefstats.html

Comment: Hint: [Kasiski Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasiski_examination)

Comment: @kelalaka: The Kasiski test is rather poorly suited for computer-assisted cryptanalysis, not to mention unreliable: it works great if you can find a couple of nice repeats, but badly or not at all if you don't.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen it is not exactly same, but similar idea.